# Expand flexbox child into full new row wider than container

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a portfolio section working with Bootstrap 4 and learning flexbox.  Each portfolio item initially contains a thumbnail that expands/collapses with more details when clicked.

At full width, the items run in rows of 4 columns.  Can I use flexbox to get the detailed description (`pabout`) to expand below the current row and run full width?  i.e.  On mobile, items will be in 1 column and clicking an item will expand the description below the item clicked.  At larger widths, the description will expand (to make a new row) below the row at full width.

Looking for the CSS for the expanded row.  I can manage the JS.

```
<section id="test" class="container">
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="pitem">             
            <div class="pcard">
                <p>Title 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pabout">
                Detailed description goes here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pitem">             
            <div class="pcard">
                <p>Title 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pabout collapse">
                Detailed description goes here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pitem">             
            <div class="pcard">
                <p>Title 3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pabout collapse">
                Detailed description goes here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pitem">             
            <div class="pcard">
                <p>Title 4</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pabout collapse">
                Detailed description goes here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Update:**
Here's some CSS/HTML I'm working with.  I don't mind if either the description div expands to the full viewport width or the Bootstrap container bounds. 
https://codepen.io/codecarson/pen/zEPXge

Comment: Consider posting the CSS, as well. And maybe even a live demo (i.e., jsfiddle.net or codepen.io). We can help you more effectively if we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sure.  Provided some extra baseline code demonstrating the working problem.

Answer (score -1):

Changing last item's `flex-grow` :

```
.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;

 //This change
  &:last-child{
     flex-grow: 5;
  }
}
```

Seems to work as brute force method. Or are you searching for something more intelligent ?

Comment: It's the blue/purple description box (currently off-center and incorrectly overlapping) that should grow and expand to fit the container width, pushing the other items down.  Thought I could perhaps use CSS but maybe I have to change the markup around to break context or use JS.